# Spring boot able to accept Enum as Request parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

So, I got into this new Spring Boot project which was already under developement and while writing API's I used `Enum` for `@RequestParam` in my controller and it worked.

I did not write any converters for this.

Later on I noticed that in this project the other developers had written custom Converter's for this.

So I decided to search the web regarding this and all solutions that came up for using `Enum` with `Controller` in Spring Boot used converter, could not find any examples without converter like how I did.

Below is one an example of how I wrote this, `LoanStatus` is an `Enum`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loans", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getPatientsLoan(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(value = "loanStatus", required = false) LoanStatus loanStatus) {}
```

So is this a relatively new feature that Spring Boot accepts `Enums` now without the need for converter's and that is why all the examples used converters or will I face some issue in feature cause I did not user converter's even though it is currently working for me?

Comment: String to enum conversion has been possible since Spring 3 (and has nothing to do with Spring Boot!). See the [`StringToEnumConverterFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToEnumConverterFactory.java). Prior to that you would have to write a custom converter/editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring has supported `String` to `Enum` conversion since Spring 3.0. There is a [`ConverterFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToEnumConverterFactory.java) which dynamically creates a converter for the specific enum.

Prior to that you would need to write a custom `Converter` or `PropertyEditor` to convert enums. But basicallly with the current versions you don't need to if the `String` matches the `Enum` name.

If you want custom enum conversion (by some internal value or whatever) you still would need a custom converter.